# how can i set slider plugin to have flexible width

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design, orbit

I am using Orbit slider http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider plugin, which seems to be a very good slider. but unfortunately i cannot make the slider flexible for adaptive design, I've tried pretty much everything it just doesn't work.

download here http://matt.zurb.s3.amazonaws.com/orbit-1.2.3.zip

my slider is currently in a 80% width wrapper

i want to make the slider change width fluidly. i can change the width of the slider in the css under `div.orbit-wrapper` and the size of the image under `.orbit img` but when setting the width of the `img` to a percentage the image dissapears and on developer tolls says it has a width and height of 1px –

```
<body>

<div id="top_bar"><p>i am a fixed top bar</p></div>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <img src="logo.png" width="400" height="100">
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
        <a href=""><p>Home</p><p>Get Started</p></a>
        <a href=""><p>About</p><p>What We Do</p></a>
        <a href=""><p>Gallery</p><p>Veiw our Work</p></a>
        <a href=""><p>Products</p><p>Browse</p></a>
        <a href=""><p>Contact</p><p>Get in Touch</p></a>
    </div>

    <div id="slider">
        <div id="featured"> 
            <img src="overflow.jpg" alt="Overflow: Hidden No More" />
            <img src="pb.png"  alt="HTML Captions" data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
            <img src="features.jpg" alt="and more features" />
        </div>
<!-- Captions for Orbit -->
        <span class="orbit-caption" id="htmlCaption">This is a caption</span>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#featured').orbit();
     });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On the website can be read:

First, Orbit will dynamically determine the height and width of your set of images and scale accordingly, but make sure all your images are the same size or the larger images will peek out on the sides.

Comment: yes im aware of this i. but i want to make the slider change width fluidly. i can change the width of the slider in the css under `div.orbit-wrapper` and the size of the image under `.orbit img` but when setting the width of the img to a percentage the image dissapears and on developer tolls says it has a width and hight of 1px

Comment: See what happens when you apply the CSS rules for background-size. Try "contain" or "cover". See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)